# What is the difference between 点字 and 点字表記?

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning

I have a picture for 点字表記, but I don't know what it means and how it is different from 点字.

[image: braille dictionary]

Answer (score 6):

点字 (lit. "dot character") means braille, and 表記 means orthography/notation.

Japanese is a language which normally uses tons of characters which include hiragana, katakana and kanji. Mixtures of these are surely difficult for learners, but once you get used to it, they also help us write and read sentences smoothly without spaces at all. We can instantly tell the word boundaries of sentences thanks to these three types of characters.

However, the Japanese 点字 system are very different from ordinary Japanese. We also use the 2×3 matrix for each "character" , but theoretically there are only 63 possible patterns (excluding the blank/space), which is enough for Latin languages but not for Japanese. See [this chart](http://www.yoihari.net/tenji/omotegazo.html) for the Japanese braille system. Simply put, writing Japanese in braille is like having to write everything only in hiragana and spaces, which is often confusing because there are many compound words and words that share the same hiragana spelling.

That's where this dictionary, 点字「表記」辞典 (braille *orthography* dictionary), comes in. If we look at its [sample (PDF)](http://www.siencenter.or.jp/tosho/dl/hyoki-page.pdf), we'll soon notice that this dictionary does not explain the meaning of words at all. Instead, this dictionary tries to standardize how to "write" certain difficult and/or complicated words. For example, this dictionary says 曖昧模糊 should be written as `あいまい□もこ` (where □ represents a space), but 青二才 should be written as `あおにさい` without any space. This surely helps professional 点字 users.

If this book were called 点字辞典, it might look like an ordinary dictionary (i.e., giving the meaning of words) written in braille. That's not the purpose of this book.

Reference: [点字は誰のもの？](http://www.yoihari.net/tenji/theory.htm) (written in Japanese)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it seems that they want to mean "braille transcription" or "braille orthography" by the phrase 点字表記. (See [the publisher's site](http://www.siencenter.or.jp/tosho/hyouki.html).)

It is a reasonable interpretation of this word (with context), but you should not expect this phrase to be an idiom always mean such a thing. You can be sure that 点字 always mean "braille" though.